# How to distinguish between higher mdpi and mdpi in android

Tags: android

I was testing on 10" tablet form factor AVD, but it has  "higher mdpi" set rather than mdpi.
In which directory in resources to put images/strings for "higher mdpi"

-Thanks

Comment: What is "higher mdpi"? Do you mean hdpi?

Comment: What does "higher mdpi" mean? How did you determine that the tablet was "higher mdpi"? Where was this set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html , you will need to put it into `(values/res/layout)-xlarge-mdpi/` folder, 10" is considered as Xlarge screen size, and you already know the dpi is mdpi.

Hope this helps,

Reid